# Animating a modal <dialog> element: Whole body moves instead

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, css-animations, css-position

The idea is to have a `<dialog>` element open as modal dialog, and on opening to slide in from the right. The following minimal example was what I came up with:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.querySelector('.slide-in').show()">open</button>
<dialog class="slide-in">
  <form method="dialog"><button>close</button></form>
</dialog>

<style>
.slide-in {
  left: auto;
  right: -200px;
}
.slide-in[open] {
  animation-name: slide-in;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  right: 0;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    right: -200px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

But for some reason when the dialog is opened, it stays put on the right side of the screen while *the whole body* moves in from the left.

Demo: https://jsbin.com/sominizona/edit?html,css,output

I assume this has something to do with the [top layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer) concept, but I’m not sure what to change to get the dialog moving instead of the whole rest of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any initial positioning styles just use `translateX`

```
@keyframes slide-in {
  0%{
      transform: translateX(100%)
  }
}
```

```css
.slide-in {
    margin-right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
} 
.slide-in[open] {
  animation-name: slide-in;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  0%{
      transform: translateX(100%)
  }
}

/*@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    right: -200px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tempor, erat vel pharetra vulputate, neque justo euismod justo, vel tristique nibh sapien a felis. Sed laoreet, lorem quis gravida sollicitudin, enim est pharetra enim, ut accumsan metus lacus a quam. Morbi faucibus quam et metus sagittis malesuada. Vivamus consectetur odio sed suscipit malesuada. Duis urna quam, pharetra id eleifend in, rhoncus id nisi. Donec sit amet porta velit. Donec pellentesque purus eget libero tincidunt, sit amet aliquet purus sagittis. Quisque in leo at leo lacinia bibendum a semper ligula.</p>
  <p>Click the button below. A modal dialog opens. It should slide in from the right. Instead the body slides in from the left, while the dialog stays put.</p>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.querySelector('.slide-in').show()">open</button>
  <dialog class="slide-in">
    <form class="inner" method="dialog"><button>close</button></form>
  </dialog>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately that doesn’t work as well for me: https://jsbin.com/domocuquna/edit?html,css,output I noticed that it strangely depends on the amount of text in the dialog (and hence its intrinsic width) and the offset by which to scroll: larger dialogs animate correctly with the 200px offset, while smaller ones don’t (but animate correctly with ~50px offset).

Comment: i don't understand why you are using initial styles? that strange happens due to it if i remove the initial style works fine for me

Comment: I need `translateY(-50%)` in my original design, but even if I remove that I see the problem. I’ve updated the https://jsbin.com/domocuquna/edit?html,css,output bin to remove the initial styles and still see this problem. The `left:auto` is there so that the dialog ends up flush right. That is, after sliding in from the right, its right edge should align with the right side of the window.

Comment: Do you want slide in from the left to right corner and align with right side of the window?

Comment: The movement should be from right to left, from outside the viewport on the right side to inside the viewport, still on the right side. In principle something like »from “100vw + element width” to “100vw - element width”«. I’ve tried a wrapped element with float, https://jsbin.com/bazicicane/edit?html,css,output , but the results are even more strange, with the dialog content bouncing in place...

Comment: Totally i am now understand

Comment: I have updated the code check @Boldewyn

Comment: Cool, that works! Thank you!